# Combining several XPaths into a single XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I've an XML file containing several `host` elements. See below for an example.

```
<host starttime="1458033438" endtime="1458033455">
      <status state="up" reason="localhost-response" reason_ttl="0" />
      <address addr="192.168.1.58" addrtype="ipv4" />
      <hostnames>
         <hostname name="ubuntu.gateway.2wire.net" type="PTR" />
      </hostnames>
      <ports>
         <port protocol="tcp" portid="22">
            <state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="64" />
            <service name="ssh" method="table" conf="3" />
         </port>
         <port protocol="tcp" portid="23">
            <state state="closed" reason="reset" reason_ttl="64" />
            <service name="telnet" method="table" conf="3" />
         </port>
      </ports>
      <os>
         <portused state="open" proto="tcp" portid="22" />
         <portused state="closed" proto="tcp" portid="23" />
         <portused state="closed" proto="udp" portid="43164" />
         <osmatch name="Linux 3.7 - 3.9" accuracy="98" line="76104">
            <osclass type="general purpose" vendor="Linux" osfamily="Linux" osgen="3.X" accuracy="98">
               <cpe>cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3</cpe>
            </osclass>
         </osmatch>
         <osmatch name="Netgear DG834G WAP or Western Digital WD TV media player" accuracy="96" line="61906">
            <osclass type="WAP" vendor="Netgear" osfamily="embedded" accuracy="96">
               <cpe>cpe:/h:netgear:dg834g</cpe>
            </osclass>
            <osclass type="media device" vendor="Western Digital" osfamily="embedded" accuracy="96">
               <cpe>cpe:/o:westerndigital:wd_tv</cpe>
            </osclass>
         </osmatch>
         <osmatch name="Linux 3.8" accuracy="95" line="77648">
            <osclass type="general purpose" vendor="Linux" osfamily="Linux" osgen="3.X" accuracy="95">
               <cpe>cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3</cpe>
            </osclass>
         </osmatch>
         <osmatch name="Linux 3.1" accuracy="93" line="76656">
            <osclass type="general purpose" vendor="Linux" osfamily="Linux" osgen="3.X" accuracy="93">
               <cpe>cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3</cpe>
            </osclass>
         </osmatch>
         <osmatch name="Linux 3.2" accuracy="93" line="77811">
            <osclass type="general purpose" vendor="Linux" osfamily="Linux" osgen="3.X" accuracy="93">
               <cpe>cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3</cpe>
            </osclass>
         </osmatch>
         <osmatch name="AXIS 210A or 211 Network Camera (Linux 2.6)" accuracy="92" line="7328">
            <osclass type="webcam" vendor="AXIS" osfamily="Linux" osgen="2.6.X" accuracy="92">
               <cpe>cpe:/h:axis:210a_network_camera</cpe>
               <cpe>cpe:/h:axis:211_network_camera</cpe>
               <cpe>cpe:/o:axis:linux_kernel:2.6</cpe>
            </osclass>
         </osmatch>
         <osmatch name="Linux 3.7" accuracy="92" line="77269">
            <osclass type="general purpose" vendor="Linux" osfamily="Linux" osgen="3.X" accuracy="92">
               <cpe>cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3</cpe>
            </osclass>
         </osmatch>
         <osmatch name="Linux 3.9" accuracy="91" line="78127">
            <osclass type="general purpose" vendor="Linux" osfamily="Linux" osgen="3.X" accuracy="91">
               <cpe>cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3</cpe>
            </osclass>
         </osmatch>
         <osmatch name="Crestron XPanel control system" accuracy="91" line="15741">
            <osclass type="specialized" vendor="Crestron" osfamily="2-Series" accuracy="91">
               <cpe>cpe:/o:crestron:2_series</cpe>
            </osclass>
         </osmatch>
         <osmatch name="Linux 2.4.26 (Slackware 10.0.0)" accuracy="91" line="34666">
            <osclass type="general purpose" vendor="Linux" osfamily="Linux" osgen="2.4.X" accuracy="91">
               <cpe>cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.4.26</cpe>
            </osclass>
         </osmatch>
         <osfingerprint fingerprint="OS:SCAN(V=6.40%E=4%D=3/15%OT=22%CT=23%CU=43164%PV=Y%DS=0%DC=L%G=Y%TM=56E7D3&#xA;OS:2F%P=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)SEQ(SP=105%GCD=2%ISR=108%TI=Z%CI=I%TS=8)SEQ(SP=&#xA;OS:105%GCD=1%ISR=108%TI=Z%CI=I%II=I%TS=8)OPS(O1=MFFD7ST11NW7%O2=MFFD7ST11NW&#xA;OS:7%O3=MFFD7NNT11NW7%O4=MFFD7ST11NW7%O5=MFFD7ST11NW7%O6=MFFD7ST11)WIN(W1=A&#xA;OS:AAA%W2=AAAA%W3=AAAA%W4=AAAA%W5=AAAA%W6=AAAA)ECN(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=AAAA%O=M&#xA;OS:FFD7NNSNW7%CC=Y%Q=)T1(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%S=O%A=S+%F=AS%RD=0%Q=)T2(R=N)T3(R=N)&#xA;OS:T4(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)T5(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S&#xA;OS:+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)T6(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)T7(R=Y%DF=&#xA;OS:Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)U1(R=Y%DF=N%T=40%IPL=164%UN=0%RIPL=G&#xA;OS:%RID=G%RIPCK=G%RUCK=G%RUD=G)IE(R=Y%DFI=N%T=40%CD=S)&#xA;" />
      </os>
      <uptime seconds="4548" lastboot="Tue Mar 15 16:01:47 2016" />
      <distance value="0" />
      <tcpsequence index="262" difficulty="Good luck!" values="8881A15E,A2265F66,91E9E2AB,6F639226,E215DCDA,9548210E" />
      <ipidsequence class="All zeros" values="0,0,0,0,0,0" />
      <tcptssequence class="other" values="117BB0,117BC9,117BE3,117BFC,117C15,117C2E" />
      <times srtt="43" rttvar="508" to="100000" />
   </host>
```

In my network, there are several computers running Linux, Microsoft and Apple operating systems. I'm interested only in displaying the "Linux" systems. I've been able to do so using the XPath below, but this is only for one attribute: the IP or where available, the MAC address.

```
//host[status[@state='up'] and os[osmatch/osclass[@osfamily='Linux']]]/address[@addrtype='ipv4' or @addrtype='mac']/@addr
```

In addition to the IP address, I need to display the name of the `hostname` and the protocols (service name (either SSH/Telnet), open/close status, and port number. I've the following XPaths:

```
//host[status[@state='up'] and os[osmatch/osclass[@osfamily='Linux']]]/hostnames/hostname[@name]

//host[status[@state='up'] and os[osmatch/osclass[@osfamily='Linux']]]/os/portused/@portid

//host[status[@state='up'] and os[osmatch/osclass[@osfamily='Linux']]]/os/portused/@open
```

I need to combine all these XPaths to generate the following output:

```
Hosts running Linux
------------------------- 
Hostname: ubuntu.gateway.2wire.net
Host IP: 192.168.1.158 
Protocols: SSH (open/22), Telnet (closed/23)
```

Is there anyway I can combine all my XPaths into a single Xpath?

Comment: You can use `concat()` to concatenate the strings together. But I'd rather do it on the application level.

Comment: Oh my god, you're right. Why didn't I think of doing it at the application level? That's a really logical suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would use XSLT for this, it could do it all in one shot -- pull out the XPaths you want and display the labels next to it.